# Master branch changes while running CI - how to avoid restarting CI? (git methodology question)

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab-ci

1. User is working on his feature branch.
2. When his feature is ready, he merges/rebases from the master branch
   to his branch, to make sure that all changes done by other
   developers are incorporated into his branch.
3. User runs a GitLab CI pipeline to make sure that his changes are
   ready for merging to the master.
4. However, his CI pipeline is quite long running (30 min?), and in the
   meantime other developers merge their changes into the master. As a
   result, by the time his pipeline completes, his branch is out of
   sync with the master again. (needs to re-fetch and rerun pipeline).
5. We don't have a dedicated integrator, who would control the traffic to the master.

Currently the workaround is setting up time slots on a shared calendar, when each developer may merge to the master. This is inefficient and not elegant.

What might be a better solution?

Note: we're considering ["Merge Trains"](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/30/all-aboard-merge-trains/), but this is a premium feature and it has it's own drawbacks.

Comment: I think you laid this out well. Could you describe what you mean about 'has its own drawbacks'? It seems like it has precisely the behavior you want. _Pipelines for merged results_ alone would probably also work, but is also a Premium feature. Short of implementing your own custom webhook, that may be your only option to have GitLab enforce this workflow.

Comment: @sytech, thanks. I'm far from an expert on Merge Trains, but for instance, AFAIK if a merge request's pipeline fails, it gets dropped from the merge train. 
In our typical use case, it is not uncommon for pipelines to initially fail. When using some kind of time slots arrangement, it allows the user a second chance. 
That said, that's something we can handle.